# Having a rendering problem on every xml file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

Almost every XML file of mine gets the following error. It looks like there could be some rendering problem, I have been using the same code in a different project before, and it did not seem to have problems with the XML files, but with this one it does. I could not find an information that suits me correctly, so I decided to write here. The error:

`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8534.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:268) at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:294) at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:131) at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934) at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008) at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:318) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127) at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130) at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505) at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353) at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450) at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122) at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:727) at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:884) at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:195) at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:293) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AppCompatTextView_emojiCompatEnabled at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEmojiTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatEmojiTextHelper.java:57) at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:127) at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:228) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:148) ... 31 more`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_black_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_image_search"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_image_search"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="user name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_full_name_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_name_search"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="user profile name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/follow_btn_search"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_full_name_search"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_black_background"
            android:text="Follow"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If someone has any idea on how to fix this I would be glad to know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you please try `AppCompatTextView`, I think legacy `TextView` is causing the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you maybe also post the code of the class?